# How to make a data-grid scrollable while placing a userControl under it in WPF app using XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a WPF application. I am rendering the data into a data-grid. I want the DataGrid to expand as need to take the full height of the screen. If there are more data than the height of the screen, I want to automatically show scrollbar.

Also, below the data-grid, I have a `ContentControl` section which renders a pagination for the data. How can I place these two under each other at the same time while showing scroll bar if needed around the data-grid.

Here is my `XAML` code

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
    <StackPanel>

        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Vendors}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVendor}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

            <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account Number"
                                    Binding="{Binding AccountCode}" />

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                    Path=DataContext.ShowVendor}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                    <fa:FontAwesome Icon="Eye"
                                                    FontSize="18" />
                                    <Label Content="Details" 
                                           Padding="7 0 0 0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                                      Path=DataContext.DeleteVendor}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                    <fa:FontAwesome Icon="Trash"
                                                    FontSize="18" />
                                    <Label Content="Delete"
                                           Padding="7 0 0 0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>


        <ContentControl Content="{Binding PageMeta}"></ContentControl>

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

I also tried to add `DockPanel` and wrap my datagrid with `ScrollViewer` but that did not work either. The scroll bar works but the `PageMeta` Content Control is not visible.

Here is how I added the ScrollViewer

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">

    <DockPanel>
        <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <StackPanel >

                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Vendors}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVendor}"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          VerticalContentAlignment="Center">

                    <DataGrid.Columns>

                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                            Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account Number"
                                            Binding="{Binding AccountCode}" />

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                            Path=DataContext.ShowVendor}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                            <fa:FontAwesome Icon="Eye"
                                                            FontSize="18" />
                                            <Label Content="Details"
                                                   Padding="7 0 0 0" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                                              Path=DataContext.DeleteVendor}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                            <fa:FontAwesome Icon="Trash"
                                                            FontSize="18" />
                                            <Label Content="Delete"
                                                   Padding="7 0 0 0" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    </DataGrid.Columns>

                </DataGrid>


        </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding PageMeta}"></ContentControl>

        </StackPanel>

    </DockPanel>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, why do you need pagination controls while having scrollbars, moreover laid over the grid ? Better explanations and a screenshot would surely help.

Comment: The user may choose to show 50 records per page. That require the scrollbar. While the user need to be able to navigate to next page... But if the user choose to show 15 records per page, there won't be a scrollbar but there would still be a pagination

Comment: Okay, have you checked what does happen to your control with either Snoop or Live Property Explorer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/inspect-xaml-properties-while-debugging) ?

Comment: Add the scrollviewer to include your ContentControl too

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick

```
<DockPanel Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}"
           Margin="0"
           LastChildFill="True"
           VerticalAlignment="Top">

    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="0 10 0 0">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding PageMeta}"></ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>


    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top">

            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Vendors}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVendor}"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        CanUserAddRows="False"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center">

            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                    Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account Number"
                                    Binding="{Binding AccountCode}" />

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                        Path=DataContext.ShowVendor}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                    <fa:FontAwesome Icon="Eye"
                                                    FontSize="18" />
                                    <Label Content="Details"
                                           Padding="7 0 0 0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                                            Path=DataContext.DeleteVendor}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                    <fa:FontAwesome Icon="Trash"
                                                    FontSize="18" />
                                    <Label Content="Delete"
                                           Padding="7 0 0 0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>


    </ScrollViewer>



</DockPanel>
```